# Using find and stat to display filename(s) and statistics

Tags: find

I'm trying to run a command to find all files starting with 'geo' and see when they were edited. I am trying to following but unfortunately am having no luck..

Is there a param for stat to display the filename or do I need a multi-line bash script...

**This works:**

```
find . -name 'geo*' -exec stat -c%y {} \;
```

**This doesn't:**

```
# find . -name 'geo*' -exec echo {}&&stat -c%y {} \;
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
find . -name 'geo*' -exec stat -c%n\ %y {} \;
```

Use `stat --help` for more info

Answer (score 2):

You can use `%n` for the file name in stat

```
find . -name 'geo*' -exec stat -c '%y       %n' {} \;
```

Alternatively, you can print the file modification time as `%Tk` (where `k` is a datetime specifier similar to those used by the 'C' [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html) function) and name `%p` directly from the find command e.g.

```
find . -name 'geo*' -printf '%Tc %p\n'
```

or in a format closer to that of `stat -y`

```
find . -name 'geo*' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %Tz    %p\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't working because the && that you append to the command:

```
execve("/usr/bin/find", ["find", ".", "-name", "geo*", "-exec", "echo", "{}"], [/* 56 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9914000
```

As you can see, the `&&` is eaten up by the shell and never reach `find`. You can use PaulB solution in this case:

```
find . -name 'geo*' -exec stat -c%n%y {} \;
./.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/X11/locale/georgian-academy2013-02-20 06:03:01.000000000 -0400
./.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/i386/usr/share/X11/locale/georgian-ps2013-02-20 06:03:01.000000000 -0400
./.PlayOnLinux/fonts/georgiai.ttf2014-03-21 17:32:48.427937178 -0400
```